# How to capture menu click (drawer) on MDL?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to capture the `click` event on the menu link (before opening left drawer).

I already tried with

```
$('div.mdl-layout__drawer-button').on('click',function(){});
```

but is not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you mean to post this on stack overflow? It's currently on super user.

Comment: Not working means what exactly? Not like you expected or not at all? Got any console errors? And what it is you're trying inside that function? You know it's currently doin nothin right?

Comment: Are you saying this event is not fired?

Comment: Well it is firing but how can I add actions to it.

Like. $("#drawer").on("shown",functionx);

Because like this...$('div.mdl-layout__drawer-button').on('click',function(){});  is not firing.